# How do I make and event and have an alert in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, button, events, event-handling

I'm having trouble making a button in each product that pops an alert and tells about the item's description. I can get the button to appear in each product but it's making the event that's giving me trouble.

Here's my code:

Product.js:

```
import React from "react"

function Products(props){

return(
    <div className="list">
        <h3>{props.product.name}</h3>
        <p style={{color: props.product.price >= 10 ? "red" : "yellow"}}>Price: ${props.product.price}</p>
        <p>{props.product.description}</p>
        <hr/>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Products

App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import productsData from "./vschoolProducts"
import Products from "./Products"
```

function App(){

```
const productsComponent = productsData.map(item => <Products key={item.id} product={item} />);

  
return (
    <div>
    {productsComponent}
    </div>
);
```

}

export default App

My Array (vschoolProducts.js):

```
const products = [
{
    
    id:"1",
    name:"Pencil",
    price:1,
    description:"Something you write with. "
},
{
    
    id:"2",
    name:"Pen",
    price:3,
    description:"Something you write with....permanently "
},
{
    
    id:"3",
    name:"Paper",
    price:7,
    description:"Something you write on. "
},
{
    
    id:"4",
    name:"Binder",
    price:4,
    description:"Useful for sorting shit. "
},
{
   
    id:"5",
    name:"Notebook",
    price:10,
    description:"Great for jotting notes down. "
},
{
    
    id:"6",
    name:"Backpack",
    price:12,
    description:"Can hold all the previous products. "
}
```

]

export default products

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right in thinking that you want every product to alert it's description when clicked then I believe you can do this. Add an onclick event to your product component.

```js
const productsComponent = productsData.map(item => <Products key={item.id} product={item} onClick={() => {alert(item.description);}} />);
```

Comment: I made another component called Button.js  for the alert and it's working. The button says "click me" on it and the alert box shows: "an alert". Now instead of the alert box displaying "an alert" I want that alert box to show the specific item's description for each of the buttons from the array. Thanks a lot for your help. I feel like I'm close.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially if I was doing something like this in my app. This is the way I would do it: Create two states, one for toggling my alert's visibility, another for holding my alert message. Then I would generate my products like this

```js
<>
<div className="list">
<h3>{props.product.name}</h3>
<p style={{color: props.product.price >= 10 ? "red" : "yellow"}}>Price: ${props.product.price}</p>
<p>{props.product.description}</p>
<hr/>

<Button
variant="outlined"
onClick={() => {

setAlertMessage(product.description);

showMyAlertComponent(true);

setTimeout(() =>
showMyAlertComponent(false)
,6000);

}}
>
Click Me
</Button>
```

What is happening above is I am creating a button for all my products and  creating an onclick listener that does the following: Sets my alert message, shows my alert and then hides it after 6 seconds. If you are using an alert component like Material -UI component, you could use autoHideDuration instead of writing the setTimeout code.

Then I just return my generated products and my alert component. I will pass the value of my alert message state to my alert component, so it changes whenever the user clicks on a different item.

```js
<>
{generationFunction}
<Alert
autoHideDuration={6000}
> 
{alertMessage}
</Alert>
</>
```

So in this way, I would need only 1 Alert component for all my items. If you are just using browser's alert function though it's even simpler.

```js
const generationFunction = products.map((product) => {

return(

<>
<div className="list">
<h3>{props.product.name}</h3>
<p style={{color: props.product.price >= 10 ? "red" : "yellow"}}>Price: ${props.product.price}</p>
<p>{props.product.description}</p>
<hr/>

<Button
variant="outlined"
onClick={() => {

alert(product.description)

}}
>
Click Me
</Button>

</div>

</>
);
});

return(generationFunction);
```

Full code

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Alert } from "@mui/material";

const products = [
{
    
    id:"1",
    name:"Pencil",
    price:1,
    description:"Something you write with. "
},
{
    
    id:"2",
    name:"Pen",
    price:3,
    description:"Something you write with....permanently "
},

];

const GenerateProducts = () => {

// create a state for my alert message
const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState("");
//create a state to toggle ur alert component, set State to false initially
const [showMyAlertComponent, setShowMyAlertComponent] = useState(false);

//generating components using your products array
const generationFunction = products.map((product) => {

// Generate buttons + Whatever other component you want to generate
//define onClick handler that sets your alertMessage and then shows it

return(

<>
<div className="list">
<h3>{props.product.name}</h3>
<p style={{color: props.product.price >= 10 ? "red" : "yellow"}}>Price: ${props.product.price}</p>
<p>{props.product.description}</p>
<hr/>

<Button
variant="outlined"
onClick={() => {

setAlertMessage(product.description);

showMyAlertComponent(true);

setTimeout(() =>
showMyAlertComponent(false)
,6000);

}}
>
Click Me
</Button>

</div>

</>
);
});

return(
<>
{generationFunction}
<Alert> 
{alertMessage}
</Alert>
</>
);

}
```

Comment: the const GenerateProducts = () => part is confusing me because the way you put the code on one page. You did break it up in 3 sections but I'm having trouble knowing where to put it. Should I but it in it's own file is my question? the last code snippet seems like I should put everything in my array. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I figured it out Thanks a lot for the help. Much appreciated.